# Write a paragraph of more than 2 lines on canvas image

Tags: canvas, textarea

**JS fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/WxmQR/1/  I want to know when the user press enter how to get the text on canvas to next line. At present its only writing everything in one single line. Thank you.

Sample Code:

```
var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
imageElem = document.getElementById('image');

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('keyup', function (){
tCtx.canvas.width = tCtx.measureText(this.value).width;
tCtx.fillText(this.value, 0, 10);
imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();    
}, false);
```

Comment: You can `split` the `value` obtained from the `textarea` using `\n`. Then you have an array, whose length indicates the number of separate lines and can draw the text accordingly. http://jsfiddle.net/h9uaQ/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `fillText` doesn't care much for `\n`. So, you need to change your `keyup` handler to detect how many newlines there are in the text, and then render it accordingly by shifting the y-coordinate.

So, in the `keyup` handler, add

```
...
var t = this.value.split('\n');
tCtx.height = t.length * 10;

var y = 10;
for(var i=0; i<t.length; i++, y+=10) {
    tCtx.fillText(t[i], 0, y);
}
...
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/K34a7/)**.